# Using CSS in an HTML Editor that doesn't allow the use of CSS classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I am using Moodle to add content to a course. I want to use an accordion using CSS and Javascript just as in the example here (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion). The HTML editor, however, does not recognise the classes - they disappear when the code is saved. The school I working for do not want to support CSS, is there anything I can do to get it working?

Comment: Kindly show screenshots of your issue and possible code.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard about Moodle editor. However, I believe that you should be able to change it's settings to use CSS. I kinda doubt that CSS is not working at all and is disappearing in an editor. However, just to be sure, add this line in your CSS:

```
html 
{ 
     display: none !important;
}
```

If you see an empty page, it means CSS is working perfectly. If you see no difference, try checking the link tag in your html (of you used external CSS). In case that doesn't work out, you can deploy your CSS code online very easily and just use the link.

Why are you using a particular editor anyway? Code's output has nothing to do with the editor. Editor is used just to edit the files and these files are compiled by the browsers in different ways (that's why browsers have different attributes compatibilities). I assume that you website is deployed online so you can go to the deployment, and download the code and try editing in a different editor like VSCode (one of the most used editor for web development)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. It sounds like the text editor you're using has anti-XSS features built in that are parsing your content and stripping out things it considers unsafe. If that's right, how you might accomplish your goal is entirely limited by the specifics of the stripping process. Sounds like the `class` attribute is stripped. I'd be surprised if *all* attributes are stripped, however. I suggest you do some testing:

- Are `id` attributes preserved? e.g. `<p id="my-paragraph">lorem ipsum</p>`
- Are `style` attributes preserved? e.g. `<p style="color: blue">lorem ipsum</p>`
- Are `<style />` tags preserved? e.g. `<style>p { color: blue }</style><p>lorem ipsum</p>`
- Link tags? e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">`
- Are `<script />` tags preserved (I highly doubt it, but might as well check)? e.g. `<script>alert('hello from script tag');</script>`
- How about `javascript:` protocols in hrefs? e.g. `<a href="javascript:alert('hello from href')">click me</a>`

Depending on if any of those succeed, you might have some opportunities to create the kind of content you're after.

Basically they don't want you scripting in this box, and by asking this question you're subverting that intent so you're hacking. Oh, which reminds me, probably don't do this, since Moodle is a Learning Management System which probably means you're a student using a school's computer system and anything remotely like hacking could get you in trouble.

Have Fun!!